# Symfony2 and AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony

Im wondering how to do asynchronous actions in Symfony2 without reloading the page. I dont find anything about on the "Book" and the "Cookbook". (Only thing I found was 2 sentences about hinclude.js?)

Im thinking of: Sending a form without reloading the page(save into db), reload parts of the page, etc.

Comment: You can use the [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle). It will allow you to generate routes in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

A rough template for a controller function.
It includes a check if ajax and just returns JsonResponse.

```
public function ajaxAction(Request $request)
{
    if (! $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException();
    }

    // do whatever
    $rtn = array('foo' => 'bar');

    return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse($rtn);
}
```

Standard ajax code to put in view;

```
<div id="my-foo">bob</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
                url: '{{ path('route_to_controller_function') }}', // path should be in your routes.php
                type: 'post',
                data: {param1: 'foo'}, // if required
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                // do whatever you want
                // for example write foo to div
                $('#my-foo').html(data.foo);
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert( "error" );
            });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes but how can I call a controller action from JS?

Comment: You can for example use Ajax and load data from url (which is mapped to a specific action ofcourse). For the other part of your question, symfony is very 'static'. The docs assume that you do not have much JS on the front-end, only except when it is urgently needed, for example with form field prototypes. I suggest you try to look for a JS front-end framework (AngularJS for example) if you need to do a lot of stuff, because with only jQuery for example, things get pretty ugly soon.

Comment: bench-o have updated my answer for you, but @tomazahlin raises a good and valid point if you are wanting to do a lot of ajax, especially with forms.

Comment: @tomazahlin are you using angularjs with symfony forms ? you must be a god

Comment: @oligan yes I am using symfony 2 form component together with angularjs. Note however that i do not use php to render the form, but i wrote my own form builder for angularjs. The Symfony's form component is used only to map the data to php objects. Symfony is only the backend - API.

Comment: @tomazahlin haaa custom forms ok then ;)

Comment: Is it normal(for web applications) to use url path's for every ajax action?

Comment: Btw. Rooneyl the shorthand version of this i found is jQuery.get which is much shorter: $('#content_div').get('{{ path("ajax_controller") }}');