# javascript ajax and post value is working all together why

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I am having a some problem in my java script and to get the request.

This is the **HTML**

```
<form method="post" id="searchform">
        <div align="center" class="col-md-10">
            <input  type="text" id= "contentSearch" name="contentSearch" >
        </div>
    <div class="form-group"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submitSearch">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search
        </button></div>
</form>
```

**<----Scenario 1 ---->**

This script works fine and post the value and as ajax it never reload the page

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitSearch").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            var data = {};
            data['contentSearch'] = $('#contentSearch').val();
            // Submit data via AJAX§
            $.ajax({
            url: '/home',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        // do i need to do something here !!
                    }
            });    
    });
    });
</script>
```

When i check the POST value i can see the value is been POST.

The Problem is when i try to get the request data from controller like  ---

```
$post_value = $request->request->get('contentSearch');
print_r($post_value);
```

> OUTPUT : empty

**<----Scenario 2 ---->**

This script have a problem i think, because it **reload** the page for returning the result and displaying the value ---

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#searchform").on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {};
        data['contentSearch'] = $('#contentSearch').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/home',
            type: 'post',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {

        }),

       return false;
    });
    });
</script>
```

than i am able to get the post value like so--

```
$post_value = $request->request->get('contentSearch');
```

But the problem is in the second script the page is always loading when return the request which is not a **ajax** behave.

And in the first script i think because of the `**e.preventDefault();**` i am not getting the POST value in my controller.

**Expected result ---**

```
Option 1 : Do something so i can get the POST value in my controller
Option 2 : Fix this script so the page do not load to return the result and display
```

I am working on symfony framework .

Can someone please help me to fix this problem, i am really getting sick of to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot on advanced.

Comment: There is too much of data variable.
Change success: function (data) to success: function (result)
and then you will get the response in result. you can use console.log(result) to see the result in console.
Also, you can see in the network log as if what is posted by the AJAX call

Comment: try changing the url....like url: "/home" or something like whatever url you want and yes success: function(response) { your code}

Comment: Change the name of your data object. Say dataParams or something else. Or quote the "data" param name in the $.ajax. Not sure what PHP Framework you are using (maybe Cake). Sure you catch POST params using $request->request->get ?

Comment: In your second scenario, it is reloading the page because you are not using e.preventDefault(). So you are launching from an <a> tag and the default behaviour is to reload.

Comment: @MarkSkayff but i think i return false in the edn of the ajax request which should do the same thing as well and i am working on Symfony framework

Comment: Ok, that's a common mistake. Your false doesn't affect the default behaviour of the <a>. Thus the existance of e.preventDefault(). Otherwise using false would suffice.

Comment: Im not sure, but try to stringify your data wit JSON.stringify() before passing it to the ajax method. I think you are passing a reference, instead of a string.

Comment: Can you confirm the element triggering the ajax is indeed an `<a>` tag?

Comment: @RussellBevan He probably edited the post and added it. I didn't see the e.preventDefault() first. And as you see he was using false assuming he was getting it right.

Comment: @MarkSkayff that's a possibility

Comment: i have tried that and it did not work, but can anyone fix the 2nd script so it never reload the page, i have also added the html to have all that u need to know

Comment: @ChristoferHansen that's what I suspected. The form submission is causing the page to reload. Instead of `click` function you need to use `submit` and then the `preventDefault` will stop the page from loading.

Comment: @ChristoferHansen Can you tell which element is triggering your "click" in the second script?

Comment: @RussellBevan Lol, it's a form.

Comment: @MarkSkayff, yes and a form submit will cause the page to reload which he clearly does not want. You can submit the form without page reload.

Comment: @ChristoferHansen You have to change the way you treat the event. You have to target the form instead of the button, and treat for the 'submit' event. Using e.preventDefault() should do the trick you are looking for too.

Comment: @MarkSkayff can u give a sample answer how i should do it, i really really frastrated on this, stuck a long time on this, really need some help

Comment: @MarkSkayff nice try. I clearly just said the exact same thing.

Comment: @RussellBevan Ah, I see your comment above. Haven't seen it. I was probably typing when you posted it. Anyway, you are right. I might upvote your answer and all as well. Besides have being downvoted by you in first place.

Comment: @MarkSkayff but I upvoted two of your comments to make up for it :)

Comment: @RussellBevan Lol, I see them. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, you need to be targeting the `submit` on the form. Not a `click` event. When targeting the `click` you are firing both the `click` and `submit` events, hence the reload.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#searchform").on('submit', function (e) {
    var data = {};
    data['contentSearch'] = $('#contentSearch').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/home',
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });

   return false;
});
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the page is still loading after making the request

Comment: @ChristoferHansen did you see that I changed the selector to `searchform` instead of `submitsearch`

Comment: yes i have copied it, so there are no changes between your answer and my trying

Comment: @ChristoferHansen try adding return false at the end as well. If that works you don't need `preventDefault()`

Comment: @ChristoferHansen Yea, I searched for it. Looks like when it's about FORMS the return false does the trick. Go for the return false at the end.

Comment: @RussellBevan I expect to you edit your answer and add the return false, if it actually makes it for Christofer 's code. It will be some fireworks and a real upvote for your answer.

Comment: @MarkSkayff doesnot make any difference, still the page is loading to make the request

Comment: @ChristoferHansen I also just noticed that I did not close my function correctly. Try the new code.

Comment: @Russel i have updated it in the Scenario 2 script, can u kindly have a look please

Comment: @ChristoferHansen I noticed a few syntax errors in the ajax call you had as well. This code I posted works in jsfiddle.

Comment: @ChristoferHansen Also Christofer, you must be sure your Javascript code is not dying when you load the page. Because if it is, maybe the "submit" might not even be processed. You should be using some tools like the Firefox or Chrome console to be sure your Javascript is ok.

Comment: @RussellBevan thanks it is working exactly like the scenario one and i am not being able to get the POST value, but thanks a lot for your help, last question , do you know how i can get that POST value !

Comment: @MarkSkayff thanks for the tip, i will do that from now

Comment: @ChristoferHansen what does your controller method look like?

Comment: See this for some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181866/symfony2-and-ajax

Comment: `/**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    function myAction(Request $request) {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $post_value = $request->request->get('contentSearch');       
        print_r($post_value);`

Comment: @ChristoferHansen you need to make sure your ajax url matches the route for that action in your controller and no problem!

Comment: @RussellBevan yes that is on the same route but i do not know why it is not getting the data, if i remove the javascript, it works fine but just reload the page

Comment: @ChristoferHansen try changing the data property on the ajax call to `data: { contentSearch : $('#contentSearch').val()}`

Comment: @RussellBevan thanks, have tried but no success, it shows there are no ajax request is been made, opened a new question here ---http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112589/no-success-post-data-html