# no success POST data html

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony

when i make a request with ajax i can see that the post value, but when i see the console log it return me this message ---

> no success post data

[image]

and also in the symfony web debug toolbar i can see what there are no ajax request have been make .

[image]

This is my html code ---

```
<form method="post" id="searchform">
        <div align="center" class="col-md-10">
            <input  type="text" id= "contentSearch" name="contentSearch" >
        </div>
    <div class="form-group"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submitSearch">
            Search
        </button></div>
</form>
```

This is my javascript code ---

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#searchform").on('submit', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/home',
        type: 'post',
        data: { contentSearch : $('#contentSearch').val()},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });

   return false;
});
});
    </script>
```

Controller code ---

routing code ---

```
content:
    path:     /home
    defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Home:home }
```

Controller code ---

```
<?php
namespace AdminBundle\Controller;    
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;    
class homeController extends Controller {
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
 // route of /home
function homeAction(Request $request) {

 if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
 $request = $request->request->get('contentSearch');
 // do something with the  $request
 $result;
}}
return $this->render('AdminBundle:Home:home.html.twig', array(
        'pageTitle' => 'my ajax',
        'menu' => $this->menu,
        'result' => $result
            )
);
```

Do any one knows how to solve this problem !!!!

Comment: where's the server code ?

Comment: And what is your controller doing for route `/home` ?

Comment: @PedroLobito i have update the question to show my controller code as well

Comment: Shouldn't it be INPUT type="submit", rather than button?

Comment: That doesn't matter @Culme. It works either way.

Comment: 1. Your controller code is not the full function, please provide the whole thing — 2. Ouch, that code.

Comment: does `$request->request->get('data');` return anything?

Comment: @tchap in my controller i am getting the POST value and if i do no get the POST value i guess rest does not matter

Comment: @RussellBevan it is returning null

Comment: @ChristoferHansen, sorry I meant `$request->request->get('request');`

Comment: Also, you don't need to override your `$request`. You should be able to just output `$request->request->get('request');` with no other code.

Comment: @RussellBevan but the problem is i guess the data is not posting, when i see the console log, it shows **NO SUCCESS POST DATA**, that is the main problem, see the pic i attached

Comment: Are you sure the data in correct? maybe it should be like this: 
data: 'contentSearch=' + $('#contentSearch').val() ?

Comment: @ChristoferHansen then that has to have something to do with your route. If you say it works without the jQuery then you are submitting to `/` and not `/home` so are you sure the route is correct?

Comment: I am sure it is a problem of the backend. Please show your full controller, including the routing

Comment: i have update my question with routing and controller, the routing is right because the view page and the request page is the same one

Comment: Yes, routing seems OK. The class name should be HomeController, not homeController to keep with standards, but this should not matter here. But I still cannot see the full controller, I only see until the line `    $req = $this->container->get('contentSearch');`

Comment: The ajax request is firing, so the front end is fine. The console.log would not fire if the ajax request failed because it's in the ajax.success function.

Comment: Yes, that is why I would like to see the full controller

Comment: @CarlosGranados i think the rest does not matter, because the request value is null like --- `$request->request->get('contentSearch');`

Comment: we can not achieve nothing when you do not get the POST value through ajax and when i ommit the ajax request i get the request fine

Comment: Well, I cannot help you if you do not want to be helped

Comment: @CarlosGranados i have update the question with most of the controller part

Comment: You say that $request->request->get('contentSearch') returns null... If you insert console.log ("Search:"+$('#contentSearch').val()) in the javascript code before the Ajax call, what do you see?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92197/discussion-between-carlos-granados-and-christofer-hansen).

Answer (score -2):

when you submit a form, the default behaviour is to load the form "action" page with the supplied input fields. if no action is specified, it simply passes the value to the current page and reloads it.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3

What you need to do is prevent the form from submitting so the ajax request can fire. use preventDefault to achieve this.

```
$("#searchform").on('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url: '/home',
    type: 'post',
    data: { contentSearch : $('#contentSearch').val()},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```

Comment: return false has the same behavior. This is not the issue.

Comment: its still better practice to use preventDefault because return false also triggers stopPropagation, which could have unintended results when all you're trying to do is prevent the default form submission behavior.

Comment: That's not entirely true as you will find that preventDefault does not stop a form submission on all browsers.

Answer (score -2):

You are sending the form twice. If you set a function with $(form).on('submit') then BEFORE the form is sent, it will do whatever you tell it to. You have to add event.preventDefault()

```
$(form).on('submit',function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  // Do Ajax
})
```

And be sure to return your Ajax response with echo.

Comment: return false has the same effect. The form is not submitting twice.